# Composer autoload: class not found in production, locally works

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I read a lot of threads about my problem but I can't find the correct solution.

I wrote my own wordpress plugin and used composer for it. Locally it works fine but when I upload my project onto my webserver I got an error message about class not found.

MyOwnHooks not found in /wp-content/plugins/my-own-hooks/myownhooks.php.

Directory of my repository:

- wp-content/

  - plugins/

    - my-own-hooks/

      - vendor/
      - inc/

        - php/

          - MyOwnHooks.php
          - GoogleContactsHelper.php
          - MyContact.php
          - MyPhoneNumber.php
    - myownhooks.php

`/wp-content/plugins/my-own-hooks/myownhooks.php`:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyOwnHooks
 */
require_once ("vendor/autoload.php");

futur22\MyOwnHooksPlugin\MyOwnHooks::runner ();
```

`/wp-content/-plugin/my-own-hooks/inc/php/MyOwnHooks.php`:

```
<?php

namespace futur22\MyOwnHooksPlugin;

class MyOwnHooks {

    public function init() {
        \add_action ( 'wp_head', array (
                $this,
                'moh_incomplete_profile_script_code'
        ) );
    }

    public static function runner() {
        $pluginx = new MyOwnHooks ();
        $pluginx->init ();
    }

    public function moh_incomplete_profile_script_code() {
        // print something
    }
}
```

`/wp-content/plugins/my-own-hooks/composer.json`:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api" : "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "futur22\\MyOwnHooksPlugin\\" : "inc/php"
        }
    }
}
```

It is confusing that it works locally with XAMPP, but not on the Linux system. Everytime I change code and pull it from repository I delete composer.lock and vendor directory to run `composer install`.

XAMPP and production server have PHP 7.3.x.

What's wrong here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: One difference I see in your autoload config vs [the examples here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) is that their path ends in a slash so maybe try `"inc/php/"`

Comment: Have, have you tried running [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)?

Comment: Finally, I would also change your `myownhooks.php` to use `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` in case the configured `include_path` is different on your production system

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helping comments.

My problem is fixed by changing files and deactivating W3 Total Cache.

`myownhooks.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyOwnHooks
 */
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use futur22\MyOwnHooksPlugin\MyOwnHooks;

MyOwnHooks::runner ();
?>
```

Added the trailing slash to `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api" : "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "futur22\\MyOwnHooksPlugin\\" : "inc/php/"
        }
    }
}
```

I deleted `vendor/` and `composer.lock`. Then used `composer install` again. I also used `composer dump-autoload` just to be sure. Since then my website works again.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should add the "use code ";
use futur22\MyOwnHooksPlugin\MyOwnHooks;
but The code should be placed in top.